# SQLiteconnection dbType always Int32 despite SqlDbType Setting

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have a block of code that preps a query here:

```
var AssetTagParam = new SQLiteParameter("@AssetTagParam", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = item.AssetTag };
var VendorParam = new SQLiteParameter("@VendorParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = item.Vendor };
var DeviceParam = new SQLiteParameter("@DeviceParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = item.Device };
var AttributeParam = new SQLiteParameter("@AttributeParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = item.Attribute };
var DeviceTypeParam = new SQLiteParameter("@DeviceTypeParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = item.DeviceType };
var SystemParam = new SQLiteParameter("@SystemParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = item.System };
var LocationParam = new SQLiteParameter("@LocationParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = item.Location };
var OnLoanParam = new SQLiteParameter("@OnLoanParam", SqlDbType.Binary) { Value = item.OnLoan };
var NotesParam = new SQLiteParameter("@NotesParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = item.Notes };
var LastModifiedTimeParam = new SQLiteParameter("@LastModifiedTimeParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = item.LastModifiedTime };
var LastModifiedPersonParam = new SQLiteParameter("@LastModifiedPersonParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = item.LastModifiedPerson };
var IsDeletedParam = new SQLiteParameter("@IsDeletedParam", SqlDbType.Binary) { Value = item.IsDeleted };

SQLiteCommand insertSQL = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO Inventory(AssetTag, Vendor, Device, Attribute, DeviceType, System, Notes, OnLoan, Location)" +
" VALUES (@AssetTagParam, @VendorParam, @DeviceParam, @AttributeParam, @DeviceTypeParam, @SystemParam, @NotesParam, @OnLoanParam, @LocationParam)", conn);

insertSQL.Parameters.Add(AssetTagParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(VendorParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(DeviceParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(AttributeParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(DeviceTypeParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(SystemParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(LocationParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(OnLoanParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(NotesParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(LastModifiedTimeParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(LastModifiedPersonParam);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(IsDeletedParam);
```

For Reference, the Item class looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int AssetID { get; set; }
    public int AssetTag { get; set; }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string Device { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
    public string System { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool OnLoan { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedTime { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedPerson { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this code, I will always run into the generic error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

After trying to figure out the source of this issue, assuming that I typed something wrong in the process, I ran into the issue that all my **Param** vars had their `dbType` set to `Int32`.  I thought I was setting with the parameter `SqlDbType.Text`, but I must be misunderstanding this?

How do I set the dbtype of my inputs to Text instead of Int32?

Comment: `SqlDbType` is for SQLServer the generic `DbType` shoud be used with SQLite - are you using the standard NET Provider?

Comment: Oh, I do see that now!  Changing 'SqlDbType.Text' to 'System.Data,DbType.String' resolves that nicely!

Comment: I dont think you want Binary for a bool either.

Comment: If you had used the other one-line syntax: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.String).Value = "something";` it would have caught the type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I was making is using SqlDbType to define the type of data.  I should have been using System.Data.DbType to define the data, so this:

```
var VendorParam = new SQLiteParameter("@VendorParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = item.Vendor };
```

Should instead be changed to this:

```
var VendorParam = new SQLiteParameter("@VendorParam", System.Data.DbType.String) { Value = item.Vendor };
```